# Change how DataGrid.ItemSource works

Tags: c#, datetime, datagrid

I am populating a table with data. Some of the data needs to show dates, and for that I used the `DateTime` object. It's part of a Contract Object that I wrote.

The problem with this approach is, that when I then want to call `table.ItemSource` and feed it a list of Contract Objects it calls `ToString()` when it populates the table, rather than ToShortDateString() as I want. Can I change that, so it calls `ToShortDateString()` instead of `ToString()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm supposing you are working with a DataGridView from WindowsForms. It works pretty much the same with other DataGrid.

You can format your date by setting the [Column.DefaultCellStyle.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.format.aspx) property.

```
myDateColumn.DefaultCellStyle.Format = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
```

Then when the date need to be print, it will call [`.ToString(string format)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) instead of `.ToString()`.

Since you use the `ShortDatePattern` of the current culture, it should gives the exact same result as `ToShortDateString()`.